# Can I take a protein shake twice a day?

Tags: protein, muscle-mass, muscle-gain, protein-shakes, high-protein

I am currently on a plan to build some muscle mass. I am 172 cm tall male and I weigh 140 pounds.
I can't afford to go to the gym so I bought a pair of dumbbells and I mostly do the following exercises - 
Overhead presses, bench presses, lunges, Romanian deadlift, bicep curls, farmer's walk, calf raises and bent over rows.
I am eating a caloric surplus and I manage to get about 120-130 grams of protein per day (mostly chicken, pork, tuna, peanut butter etc). I take one whey protein shake after my workout with milk (making that a total of 30g protein per shake, my 120-130g estimate is including this)
My question is should I increase it to twice a day? I have googled this and I mostly hear people saying it will lead to bloating, indigestion etc. 
Is it safe for me to increase my intake or would I be overdoing it.
I am sorry if this is the wrong place to post this. Any recommendations on my workout plan are also welcome.

Comment: It's not unsafe, but I agree that it will cause bloating. You don't need to ingest that much protein per day, and whatever surplus of protein you take in, will be stored as fat. Don't focus too much on just protein. Carbohydrates and fats are equally important, not to mention all the vitamins and minerals you should be taking care of too. If you're worried about not getting enough food, eat more food. Don't replace food with shakes.

Comment: Can I eat 2 large pizzas a day? Yes! Do I **need** to? No!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your daily protein intake is very high and very good already.I don't think you need to add another protein shake as you are right now and probably not in the near future as well.

Regarding the problems you mentioned it is a a problems that varies from person to person.I personally don't have any digestion problems no matter how many shakes i take but again this depends on each person.So the only way to find out is to try it yourself and see how your body reacts.

In conclusion,you do not need anymore protein intake right now and you probably won't need for another year or so.Just keep working out and results will come.Protein is not everything carbs fats and fiber are also important.As long as you keep a caloric surplus and you eat 120-150 gr of protein everyday you will be seeing great results in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a different perspective; if you stick to your current program/diet and don't see the results after a month or two (gaining a lb per week is a good goal), adding another shake definitely won't hurt. I try to get 1-1.5 grams of protein per lb of bodyweight, and that includes 2 protein shakes(one after workout, one before bed).

If you find you feel bloated try it with water instead of milk. If you feel bloated even with water, give it a few days for your body to adjust, if you still feel sick, you will have to stick to one.

Lots of arguments on how much protein you body needs/can absorb. I find it differs greatly from person to person, as well as how lean you are and how strenuous your lifestyle/workouts are. Personally I see much better results when I get atleast a gram per pound.

Good luck